# Calling method with "out" parameter from dynamically loaded dll?

Tags: c#, dll, reflection

I'm using reflection to load my dll. I can call its methods, get its parameters, etc. But can't figure out how to call a method that has an `out` parameter. Here's an example of a method I'm trying to call

Dll out method

```
public void GetNumber(out int number)
{
    ......
    number = 5;
}
```

I tried with the following, but number value is not changing.

```
int number = 0;
myType.InvokeMember("GetNumber", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, myInstance, new object[] { number });
```

How can I achive this?

Comment: Oops my bad, let me fix that

Comment: Yes, just tested it and it worked. Thanks to the one that posted the link. I didn't find that answer when I did my search.